# Can AJAX be used on heavy DB operations

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, vb.net

I have a web application which has lots of dropdowns and grids on it.

Currently when value of one dropdown changes , the items in the related drop down gets populated(heavy DB operation) and infact whole page is posted to the server.

Question is can Ajax be recommended in such a case? I have heard that Ajax is only good for light operations.

Comment: Do the options change frequently or are they user-specific? If not, I would consider caching that information on the webserver so you don't have to make the trip to the db each time, in which case ajax would be an excellent choice.

Comment: I agree with both Karl and Rob both are good answers - I'd also look at what can be done to speed up the long running operation - caching has been mentioned but have you looked into the execution plans of the long running queries? If you using sql server 2008+ theres an option to show exec plan when you run the query inSSMS this will often give you hints and code to implement the hints (usually missing indexes) that ca make a huge difference. Also consider ceating some views in cases where you doing nested sql queries and joind noto those instead of nesting - can also be very helpful.

Comment: Ajax works in the client side, so it will do nothing on the DB, your server will be the one taking the load, so the question is, can Ajax handle the response? If it is a really big response from the server you have to make sure your buffer can take it all. You should also have in mind, that when all of the data is trying to render, you have no power over how fast it is going to...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use ajax but I would like to offer an alternate solution...

Use ajax/post/whatever to start the process then request feedback at regular intervals using one of:

- JS polling (setInterval)
- Server-Send-Events
- SignalR

This way, the user can navigate away while waiting for the operation to complete. When "action completed" feedback is received, you can alert the user with a tidy looking in-page notification or email if more appropriate.

Comment: @SNash. Thanks! Don't forget to mark the most helpful answer as correct.

Answer (score 3):

Yes it can be, just give some sort of feedback to the user that the operation takes a while. Display a message or loading image while the operation is being performed, and then hide it when the operation is done.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is of course you can use AJAX for heavy DB operations, but maybe the better question is SHOULD you use it; the answer is it depends. Scissors are good for cutting paper, but not the yard; right tool for the right job.

Stepping back for a second, it sounds like your development technology choice may be part of your problem, as much as it is whether or not to use AJAX for heavy DB calls. My point is, if you are trying to avoid full postbacks for the page, then you might consider a more client-based implementation (such as KnockoutJS, Backbone, Ember, AngularJS, etc.) which can use calls to the server just to get the data it needs for a particular portion of the screen (via view models).